# Open problems in fiber bundles theory

Tags: big-list, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

As the title says, what are some problems in fiber bundles theory (especially principal bundles) that are still open?

Comment: Flat principal bundles is a large and active subject with many open problems; see  e.g. https://www.msri.org/programs/282 as a starting point.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek From your link I don't understand which are these open problems: would you make some example?

Comment: I am not working in this area, but I know it is active and hence obviously there are many open problems. I did not post this as an answer precisely because details are not on my fingertips. You can find surveys/problem lists in the area by standard methods (searching for keywords, names of main contributors etc). The program announcement I linked to has both. Incidentally, a flat $G$-bundle over a space $B$ is given by a homomorphism $\pi_1(B)\to G$.